# Trying to return the latitude and longitude value from leaftlet geocoder

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I've been trying to figure out how I can fetch or return the value from `geocoder` block and use the value in another `function`. I keep getting an `variable is not defined` error

```js
geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();
var location = $('.location').text();

geocoder.geocode(location, function(results) {    
        var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
        var marker = new L.Marker (latLng);
        // console.log(Object.values(latLng));   

        var geocodeLocation = Object.values(latLng);
});
    
function loc() {

      console.log(geocodeLocation);
      
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/perliedman-leaflet-control-geocoder/1.9.0/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    
    
      <span class="location">Philippines</span>
```

Comment: Declare `geocodeLocation` outside of the geocode block and then assign it

Comment: I did that before and it returned an `undefined` result

Comment: Then please provide a working example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If geocoder.geocode is asynchronous and you declare geocodeLocation globally, there's no way to know that when you'll actually use that variable it will have been set by the callback function. Can't you call your function loc inside the callback?

Answer (score 3):

As said in my comment, if you declare geocodeLocation globally and the function geocoder.geocode is asynchronous, then there’s no guarantee that the variable will be set when you’ll use it. The only way I can think of to solve this (that is, using geocodeLocation elsewhere) is using Promises. This way you can actually return geocodeLocation.

A quick explanation about how asynchronous execution works. (Don't worry I also used to ask how to return from an asynchronous call).

Say we have two functions

```
function1()
function2()
```

and `function1()` is asynchronous. What that means is that `function2()` won't wait that `function1()` ends to start running. But `Geocoder.geocode`'s callback (the function you pass to it) will be called only when it finishes its asynchronous operation. But `function2()` will have already been called..

But there is way to return a value(using async/await), something along these lines:

```js
function geocode(location, func) { //that's the geocoder.geocode
  //calculate coordinates with location
  var results = { coordinates: { lat: '37.423021', long: '-122.083739' } }
  func(results);
}
    
async function fetchGeocodeLocation(location) {

  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //wrap your geocoder.geocode function in a Promise
    geocode(location, function(results) { 
      //var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
    //var marker = new L.Marker (latLng);
    // console.log(Object.values(latLng));   

    //var geocodeLocation = Object.values(latLng);  

      resolve(results.coordinates);
    });
  });

  var geoCodeLocation = await promise;
  return geoCodeLocation;
}

fetchGeocodeLocation("somewhere").then(geoCodeLocation => console.log("geoCodeLocation", geoCodeLocation))
```

Or, say your loc() function is asynchronous, then like so

```js
function geocode(location, func) {
  //calculate coordinates with location
  var results = { coordinates: { lat: '37.423021', long: '-122.083739' } }
  func(results);
}
    
function fetchGeocodeLocation(location) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //wrap your geocoder.geocode function in a Promise
    geocode(location, function(results) { 
      //var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
    //var marker = new L.Marker (latLng);
    // console.log(Object.values(latLng));   

    //var geocodeLocation = Object.values(latLng);  

      resolve(results.coordinates);
    });
  });
}

async function loc() {
  var location = "somewhere";
  var geoCodeLocation = await fetchGeocodeLocation(location);
  console.log("geoCodeLocation", geoCodeLocation)
}

loc()
```

---

And finally, a quick explanation about **async/await**.

**What does the await do?**

It waits that the promise resolves before executing anything that comes after the await line. Without await, anything that comes after it will be executed before the promise resolves. You will get a promise in pending state.

**Why must we use await in an async function?**

The line with await might take 30 seconds to execute and your browser will freeze (that's also why ajax calls are asynchronous). The browser will ask you if you want to terminate that script that's freezing the browser (someone been doing something bad). So the async says the function is asynchronous, anything that comes after the function call won't wait that it finishes before starting. However, the await makes sure that anything that comes after it won't be executed before the promise resolves.